# Submit form downloads php script

Tags: php

When I submit this form it downloads the php script it refers to:

```
<form action="insertcustomer.php" method="post" class="myform">
<p>
    Name: &nbsp; <input type="text" name="name" size="20"/>
</p>
<p>
    Address: &nbsp; <input type="text" name="addr" size="40"/></p>
<p>
    City: &nbsp; <input type="text" name="city" size="20"/>
    State: &nbsp; <input type="text" name="state" size="3"/>
    Phone: &nbsp; <input type="text" name="phone" size="15"/>
</p>
<p>
    Account Balance: &nbsp; <input type="text" name="acct_balance" size="13"/>
</p>
<p class="bttn">
    <input class="b" type="submit" name="query" value="Insert Customer"/>&nbsp;
    <input class="b" type="reset" name="reset" value="Clear Form"/>
</p>

</form>
```

Insertcustomer.php:

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$addr = $_POST['address'];
$city = $_POST['ccity'];
$state = $_POST['cstate'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$acct_balance = $_POST['acct_balance'];
```

Is there something wrong with the code? I have followed all steps mentioned in this [article](http://maestric.com/doc/mac/apache_php_mysql_snow_leopard), but every time I click on the submit button, it downloads the php file. I apologize in advance as I am fairly new to php.

Comment: You need to wrap your page in <?php ... ?>.  Also, are you hosting the php script on a webserver that supports PHP?  If you're perhaps loading it directly from disk (as we often do during development) then nothing is in place to process the PHP code.

Comment: Create a `phpinfo.php` file with the following contents: `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`. If you see a list of PHP information, PHP is configured properly.

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention it is wrapped in <?php ?>. I have loaded and set up apache (going to localhost returns the "It works!" page).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Make sure your code is wrapped in `<?php` and `?>`
- Does your server support PHP?
- Is your server configured properly?

Comment: Update: I think it was a problem with the directory I was storing the files in. I now have them in /library/webserver/documents. I also created the phpinfo.php file and received the php output so i know php is running. Now It doesn't try to download the file, instead I get the error message "Connection Failed: No such file or directory"